# Loans based on deposit?

Tags: riba, money

Is it permissible to give an interestless loan in which the loaning party holds a sentimental item of the one taking the loan until the loan is paid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**رهن** is permissible as proven from the Quran and Sunnah:

> وإن كنتم على سفر ولم تجدوا كاتبا فرهان مقبوضة فإن أمن بعضكم بعضا فليؤد الذي اؤتمن أمانته وليتق الله ربه
>
> And if you are on a journey and cannot find a scribe, then a security deposit [should be] taken. And if one of you entrusts another, then let him who is entrusted discharge his trust [faithfully] and let him fear Allah, his Lord.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:283](http://quran.com/2/283)</sup>

> اشترى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم من يهودي طعاما ورهنه درعا من حديد
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) bought from a Jew grain (as loan) and pledged him his iron coat-of-mail.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/22/154)</sup>